# Game Of Life game: Check 2D array 8 closest surroundings; ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException issue

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, double, conways-game-of-life

I have encountered this problem and i couldn't find the solution. There is a 2D array with only zeros and ones in it (the size of the array doesnt really matter, i worked with 10x10). Zero means dead and 1 is alive. I double for looped this to check the elements sorroundings and when it sorrounded with other "cells" the code would work fine. But when its in the corner or one of the other edge of the array then it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
My question is how to write a code for this without handle all the possible situation?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] grid = {
            {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
            {1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0},
            {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
            {0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
            {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
            {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
            {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
    };

    Simulation sm = new Simulation(grid);
    sm.printOutOriginalGrid();
    sm.gameOfLife();
}
```

}

```
public class Simulation {

private int[][] grid;

public Simulation(int[][] grid){
    this.grid = grid;
}
public  void printOutOriginalGrid() {
    System.out.println("Original grid");
    for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.grid[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(this.grid[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}

public int[][] gameOfLife() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.grid.length; j++) {
            int currentCell = this.grid[i][j];
            if(currentCell == 1){
                int currentCellNeighbours = numberOfAliveNeighbours(i,j); 
            }
        }
    }

    return new int[12][12];
}

private int numberOfAliveNeighbours(int i, int j){
    int numberOfAliveNeighbours = 0;

    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i-1][j-1];
    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i][j-1];
    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i+1][j-1];

    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i-1][j];
    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i+1][j];

    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i-1][j+1];
    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i][j+1];
    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i+1][j+1];

    return numberOfAliveNeighbours;
}
```

}

Comment: return new int[12][12]; is just a random return for the compiler

Comment: this is not a valid location `int[12][12];`  also in method `numberOfAliveNeighbours()` pass 2D array size to check you are not moving out of array index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `numberOfAliveNeighbours` method, you have to test for an array index less than zero or greater than the size of the array - 1.

In other words, an int array 8 values long has index values from 0 - 7.

Here's your code fixed up.

```
public class GameOfLife {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] grid = { 
                { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, 
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 
                { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, 
                { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, };

        Simulation sm = new GameOfLife().new Simulation(grid);
        sm.printOutOriginalGrid();
        sm.gameOfLife();
    }

    public class Simulation {

        private int[][] grid;

        public Simulation(int[][] grid) {
            this.grid = grid;
        }

        public void printOutOriginalGrid() {
            System.out.println("Original grid");
            for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.grid[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(this.grid[i][j] + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }

        public int[][] gameOfLife() {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.grid[i].length; j++) {
                    int currentCell = this.grid[i][j];
                    if (currentCell == 1) {
                        int currentCellNeighbours = 
                                numberOfAliveNeighbours(i, j, grid.length);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new int[12][12];
        }

        private int numberOfAliveNeighbours(int i, int j, int limit) {
            int numberOfAliveNeighbours = 0;
            int a = i - 1;
            int b = i + 1;
            int c = j - 1;
            int d = j + 1;

            if (c >= 0) {
                if (a >= 0) {
                    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[a][c];
                }
                numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i][c];
                if (b < limit) {                    
                    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[b][c];
                }
            }

            if (a >= 0) {
                numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[a][j];
            }
            if (b < limit) {
                numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[b][j];
            }

            if (d < limit) {
                if (a >= 0) {
                    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[a][d];
                }
                numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[i][d];
                if (b < limit) {
                    numberOfAliveNeighbours += this.grid[b][d];
                }
            }

            return numberOfAliveNeighbours;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks so neat and to be honest, because it is. I have tried similar things but that didnt worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well...since I've already done it, I'm going to post my answer (I'm not as fast as @GilberLeBlanc).

As you already know there are 8 possible neighbors that can be acquired from within the matrix so we need to ensure that each directional cell neighbor is indeed within bounds of that matrix...this is obvious. Iterating through each direction of the supplied matrix cell and only carrying out an increment on valid cells (within bounds) which contain the very same value as the cell element initially supplied by `i` and `j` to the **numberOfAliveNeighbours()** method:

Here is my quick take on it:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] grid = {
            {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
            {1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0},
            {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
            {0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
            {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
            {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
            {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        };

        Simulation sm = new Simulation(grid);
        sm.printOutOriginalGrid();
        sm.gameOfLife();
    }
}

public class Simulation {

    private int[][] grid;

    public Simulation(int[][] grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    public void printOutOriginalGrid() {
        System.out.println("Original grid");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(this.grid[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }

    public int[][] gameOfLife() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.grid[i].length; j++) {
                int currentCell = this.grid[i][j];
                if (currentCell == 1) {
                    int currentCellNeighbours = numberOfAliveNeighbours(i, j);
                    // Do what you want with value in currentCellNeighbours.
                    System.out.println("Cell " + i + ", " + j + " has " + 
                                       currentCellNeighbours + " neighbours.");
                }
            }
        }
        
        // return whatever you're preparing to do...
        return new int[12][12];
    }

    private int numberOfAliveNeighbours(int i, int j) {
        /* In a matrix there can be 8 possible neighbours. 
           We need to check if a specific neigbour is actually
           within bounds before checking its value.       */
        int[][] directions = {
            {-1, -1}, // Top/Left
            {0, -1}, // Top
            {1, -1}, // Top/Right
            {-1, 0}, // Left
            {1, 0}, // Right
            {-1, 1}, // Bottom/Left
            {0, 1}, // Bottom
            {1, 1} // Bottom/Right  
        };

        int numberOfAliveNeighbours = 0;  // Start with 0 neighbours

        // Iterate through all the different directions...
        for (int[] d : directions) {
            int dx = d[0];  // Current directional Cell Row
            int dy = d[1];  // Current directional Cell Column
            /* Is the current directional cell within bounds and 
               if it is, does the directional cell element equal 
               the supplied cell element (i, j)?           */
            if ((i + dx) >= 0 && (i + dx) < (grid.length)
                    && (j + dy) >= 0 && (j + dy) < (grid[0].length)
                    && grid[i + dx][j + dy] == grid[i][j]) {
                // Yes it does...increment the neighbour count.
                numberOfAliveNeighbours++;
            }
        }
        // Return the determined neighbour count.
        return numberOfAliveNeighbours;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much too. Yeah GilberLeBlanc was a bit faster but i still appreciate your answer. :D i like also this solution because its more compact and it seems easy except that if statement:P This is also worked for me.